# Light is made up of matter, isn’t it?

Tags: visible-light, photons, matter

What’s the hype about all this conversation of light into matter? I mean it’s no big deal right? Light has particles (a form of matter) i.e.  photons in it, so what’s the big deal in conversation of that into other forms of matter? Or are photons not considered a form of matter? If not why?

Comment: Do you want to hear other people's thinking about why photons are not considered material (made of matter), or do you want to push your alternative viewpoint on what matter should be defined as? Based on your comments to the posted answers it seems you are discussing semantics, i.e. the meaning of the word "matter". Is that what your are asking?

Comment: You seem to be arguing with people who are trying to help you.  Chill out !  This isn't a discussion-type forum where you open multiple conversations with people.  It's supposed to be one well-focused question (and yours is not particularly clear IMO) and answers and related comments should *stick to that limited topic*.  You may think there are convenient definitions we should be giving you in a couple of sentences, but it's a deceptively difficult question with lots of subtlety.

Comment: This question (the first part of it anyways) is written so as to be provocative rather than informative…

Answer (score 5):

The modern definition of matter is that it is anything that is made up of fermions - particles with half-integer spin, such as quarks or electrons. The rationale behind this is that the [Pauli exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle) applies to such particles, which leads to matter having the property of taking up space, one of the parts of the classical definition of matter.

Photons, on the other hand, are bosons. They have integer spin; the Pauli exclusion principle does not apply to them so they are not counted as matter.

Comment: What is the definition of particles then? If all of them don’t make up matter then what explains their existence? Why are they present in the universe? Cause physics say Energy is definitely NOT made up of particles, although no one explains what Energy exactly is and it’s just a convention, but here the question is what are these particles for if they neither make up Matter nor Energy?

Comment: @A.M. For a list of the elementary particles that we know about see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle. Some of these particles are fermions, which make up matter; the rest are bosons. Although conventionality labelled as “particles”, each of these elementary objects can also behave as a wave - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave–particle_duality. Energy/mass is not a separate particle, but is an attribute of elementary particles and combinations of these particles such as protons, neutrons, atoms etc.

Comment: I would add, maybe, anything that is not its own antiparticle. That is, matter must be distinct from its complementary anti-matter. The photon fails this test (and has other bosonic problems), as does the Majorana neutrino. If it exists, it _is_ matter....but it's also antimatter, and that creates a small conundrum in the definition of matter...at least for me.

Answer (score 4):

> Or are photons not considered a form of matter?

No.

> If not why?

Their rest mass is 0.

But they still carry *momentum*, which is why photons can, e.g., knock electrons from atoms.

I'd say the big deal is that something that has no mass can produce massive particles. One such process is *[pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production)*, where a photon, in the presence of some other massive particle for momentum conservation, can create an electron/positron pair.

On a philosophical note, what does it mean to answer the question what something *is*? Physics does not go there. Physics *describes* the properties of the world as we find it performing measurements. We use mental constructs like "tiny hard balls" when they appear useful (e.g. to describe molecules in a gas), but these constructs sometimes fail to be useful when we look close enough. Photons are certainly no tiny hard balls ("particles") in many circumstances.

Comment: But they’re particles, aren’t they? Particles make up matter! And what if the photons do have mass but we don’t have the kind of scale to measure their mass? Besides I couldn’t find any concrete unambiguous definition that defines particles and matter properly. Can you provide me with a source that defines particles and matter unambiguously please.

Comment: @A.M. They can *act like particles* under certain circumstances. But they can also *act like waves* (e.g. light shows interference, which particles can't). So it is not really useful to describe photons as particles, because that picture is quite incomplete. If you jump in at the deep end, photons are described using wave equations and complex functions.

Comment: But vision is only explained in the form of particulate nature of light, waves can’t explain vision! And why did you answer a No, if the picture is still quiet incomplete and we don’t have all the answers?

Comment: @A.M. It's not that simple. Vision is also caused by light/electron interaction. The best description we have for this is Quantum Electrodynamics (QED). You are indeed rethinking what physicists call the *wave/particle duality* to give you a search term :-)

Comment: That’s what I’m saying light as in its particulate nature interacts with the cells of the retina. Do you know the physiology of vision, We can only see the images on a straight path, why do you think so? Waves can bend right, they do bend indeed, so why aren’t we appreciating the curvature of our planet on beaches and hills? Why do we see horizon if it isn’t even there! Because light waves are not the ones responsible for vision but light rays are, and scientists define them as beams of photons. The particles of light interact with the photo receptors of our eyes.

Comment: Saying _because it acts like a particle, it is matter_ is the same as saying _all that glitters is gold_.

Comment: @noah Metaphors and baseless analogies have no place in physics. Thank you!

Comment: Not understanding an analogy does not necessarily mean the analogy is flawed or baseless.

Comment: @A.M. Light travels along a straight line (in vacuum and a flat spacetime). The bending happens only if there is refraction (think lenses, air density variations) or diffraction (behind edges and small holes). Astronauts on the moon certainly see the true horizon, since there is no air to refract light. Even on Earth, the apparent horizon is usually close to the geometric horizon. Again, vision starts as a photon/electron interaction described by QED, no matter what chemistry and neurology follows after that.

Comment: @A.M. The concept of *rays of light* or beams in geometric optics has limitations like the tiny hard balls concept. E.g., it can't describe diffraction, while waves describe it perfectly. So if you really want to know what's going on, there's no way around understanding waves and QED.

Comment: @A.M. In a deep end nutshell: all of physics is described as fields, and "particles" are excitations of fields. The photon is an excitation of the electromagnetic field. The electron is an excitation of the electron field. Fields "couple" to one another, which is how photons can create electron/positron pairs: an excitation of the electromagnetic field converts to one excitation each of the electron and positron fields. It's that easy :-)

Comment: @noah But glitter IS gold in colour, it’s not the fault of glitter that the element gold (Au) having the colour gold is described by the same name! You’re not even setting a clear premise as to what gold you’re referring to, the elemental gold or the colour gold cause the colour gold can be produced independent of the elemental gold (Au). Besides gold is not even the true name of that element, it’s Aurum, hence Au!  And that’s how your analogy is flawed. I didn’t even think I’ll have to explain it! Have a good day.

Comment: @A.M. Ah, I see the problem now. You seem to be here only for semantic pedantry. Note that this site is mainly aimed at people being genuinely curious about the way nature works.

Comment: @A.M. Saying _gold_ is not the name of the element with atomic number 79, because it's really _aurum_, is like saying _nose_ is not the name for the thing in the middle of your face, because it's really _nasus_.